# problems migrating k8s to RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, cert-manager

so basically i changed my website to a new kubernetes cluster. Now it is necessary to enable RBAC. The pipeline runs without any errors but unfortunately the certmanager SSH doesn't work anymore. I installed certmanager with gitlab so now I'm wondering if this could have anything to do with the change to RBAC? Unfortunetally i'm new with RBAC so I don't really understand if it could be related or not. Can anybody help?

Here is a picture from the error when I run whynopadlock:

[image: whynopadlock 1]

[image: whynopadlock 2]

Edit: This is the output when I run:

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default
```

[image]

Comment: Mandatory K8s meme: https://twitter.com/caiobegotti/status/1248279288794808320 and https://twitter.com/memenetes/status/1248717546913742853

Answer (score 1):

Deploy cert-manager to managed cluster for SSL certificates is an issue requested for the past two years ([issue 40635](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/40635))
[Issue 29650](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/29650) shows the all process is not yet well documented.

But you still have an [ingress working with cert manager](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/40635#note_130063501), meaning having the annotations expected by a cert manager:

- `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`
- `kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"`

That could help with [RBAC](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/rbac.html), even though [issue 33186](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/33186) shows this setup as not fully working.

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm checking the log from the nstall-certmanager pod. There are no errors.

Comment: @user9468014 In your setup, did you install an ingress (as in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/40635#note_130063501) for the cert manager to talk to?

Comment: yes the ingress is installed. The exact same setup used to work with RBAC disabled that makes me think that it is probably an RBAC issue.

Comment: I added the output from 'kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default' in case somebody more experienced then me can help me with this.